# Application.Worksheetfunction Sumproduct issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet and I am trying to use a countifs formula to count the number or records meeting multiple conditions, however in one of the columns there are multiple criterias so I used SUMPRODUCT together with the COUNTIFS function.

I got it to work fine in the sheet but I have no idea on how to get it to work in VBA.

This is what I tried:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
FirstDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C7")
SecondDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E7")

   Application.Worksheetfunction.Sumproduct(CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("E2:E" & lastrow), ">=" & FirstDate, Sheet2.Range("E2:E" & lastrow), "<=" & SecondDate, Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), {"John";"James";"Peter"}))
```

I keep getting an error when using the above formula. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is the formula I'm trying to mimic:

=Sumproduct(CountIfs(Sheet2!E2:E1000000,">="&Sheet1!C7,Sheet2!E2:E1000000,"<="&Sheet1!E7,Sheet2!E2:E1000000,{"John";"James";"Peter"}))

I don't want VBA to insert this formula into the cell, I'd rather have it calculate the value and then insert the result into the chosen cell.

Comment: `CountIfs` is not a VBA method, so you need to also qualify that with `Application.Worksheetfunction`. You *might* also need to change that `{...}` to an array. And assign the return value of the whole expression to a variable.

Comment: Also change this `{"John";"James";"Peter"}` to  `{""John"";""James"";""Peter""}`

Comment: Can you update your question to include the worksheet formula you're trying to mimic?

Comment: Either use `Countifs` or `Sumproduct`. No need to use both.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have updated the question. Can u also elaborate on what you mean when you say use an array. I have tried assigning the return value to a variable, however the expression gives an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just heading out, so can't write a full response just now, but you could instead look at using `Evaluate(yourFormulaHere)` instead of taking the application.Worksheetfunction approach.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't believe u can use the LastRow variable in a formula with evaluate. Any thoughts?

Comment: See my answer below (I did figure out the worksheetfunction approach.  `Evaluate` takes a string argument, so if you were to use that you'd just replace the `1000000` in your existing formula with `lastRow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim v, wsf
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    v = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs( _
        Sheet2.Range("E1:E" & lastrow), ">=" & Sheet1.Range("C7").Value, _
        Sheet2.Range("E1:E" & lastrow), "<=" & Sheet1.Range("E7").Value, _
        Sheet2.Range("P1:P" & lastrow), Array("John", "James", "Peter")))

    Debug.Print v

End Sub
```

Comment: The above formula has been working very well, but I wanted to make a little adjustment with no luck so far. I want to use Array as a criteria in 3 different cases but it keeps giving me the wrong result: `a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(wsf.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("P2:P" & lastrow), Doctors, Sheet2.Range("M2:M" & lastrow), Emergency,Sheet2.Range("O2:O" & lastrow), Profession))` **where** `Doctors = Array("Peter","Sam","Henry")` **&** `Emergency = Array("Y","N")` **&** `Profession = Array("A","B")`

Comment: I have also tried the wsf.transpose method but that only seems to work upto 2 criteria. Would really appreciate your insight.

Comment: I saw your other question but was unable to figure out how to solve it.  Sorry - I only managed to answer this one after a lot of trial and error....